# How to separate and use alphabet search and datatable in to two different HTML div on same page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using responsive data tables and alphabet search together in an app, 
I've everything ready.

Code Snippet is not working on stackoverflow or i do not know how to properly include the code.. please see on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx5arbnt/51/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    dom: 'Alfrtip',
    alphabetSearch: {
      column: 0
    },
    responsive: true
  });
});
```

```css
table.dataTable.select tbody tr,
table.dataTable thead th:first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.1.1/js/dataTables.alphabetSearch.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.1.1/css/dataTables.alphabetSearch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/r-2.1.1/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/r-2.1.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<h3><a href="http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-alphabetical-search/">jQuery DataTables – Alphabetical Search</a></h3>
<a href="http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-alphabetical-search/">See full article on Gyrocode.com</a>
<hr><br>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Now the thing is i want to separate and use alphabets somewhere in a different division on the same page.  i dont want to see alphabets on top of the datatable.

How to display/call only alphabets in a different div?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to manipulate markup for `A` feature and the rest of the table. Use custom CSS to modify appearance of the alphabet control.

For example.

**JavaScript**

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   dom: '<"alphabet-container"A><"table-container"lfrtip>',
   alphabetSearch: {
      column: 0
   },
   responsive: true
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.alphabet-container {
   float: left;
   width: 10%;   
}

.table-container {
   float: left;
   width: 90%;
}

.alphabet-container .alphabet-info,
.alphabet-container .alphabet-info-display { 
   display: none 
}

.alphabet-container .alphabet ul,
.alphabet-container .alphabet li,
.alphabet-container .alphabet a {
   display: block;
}

.alphabet-container .alphabet {
   margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.alphabet-group td:first-child::before {
   display:none !important;
}
```

#### EXAMPLE

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/dx5arbnt/66/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

[jQuery DataTables AlphabetSearch](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-alphabetsearch/) - feature plug-in for the jQuery DataTables library that provides A-Z alphabetical search feature.

Comment: Thanks very much, Expanding and collapsing in responsive thing working great but any idea why that green "plus icon" got disappeared . ?

How to bring that icon back please?

Comment: @RajuLOCM, updated the answer adding support for responsive extension. I also eliminated green icon for group rows.

Comment: Thanks so much sir, i really appreciate your help.